# How can I return Json in .NET 8?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-8.0

In my `ProductController`, I have this code to return Json:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAllProduct()
{
    List<Product> objProductList = _unitOfWork.ProductRepository
                                              .GetAll(includeProperties: "Category")
                                              .ToList();

    // return Json(new { data = objProductList });
    return Json(objProductList);
}
```

And when I run the web and route to action, I get this error - please help:

[image: Screenshot]

Code has been upload here for investigation https://github.com/nguyentuananh921/Bulky_MVC/commits/master

Comment: It would be great if you could share your ERROR code instead of screenshot. 
Post the error as text, not images. Images can't be copied, googled or tested.

Comment: Do you set a breakpoint at `List<Product> objProductList` ? Can you get the value ?

Comment: `Bulky_MVC/commits/master` - is this a private repo, because we can't see a private one. And I can't see this one, it's 404 for me.

Comment: Sorry sir, I have made it to Public, please try it.
I have set the breakpoint at this List<Product> objProductList
And I can see the value.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Such errors usually are a sign of some package mismatch. Run in command line: `dotnet --list-sdks` and check that output contains latest .NET 8 preview (currently it is `8.0.100-preview.6.23330.14`, if not - install it). Also run `dotnet --version` via command line in the project folder and make sure correct version is shown.

Also delete the following package from the `Models` project:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="2.2.0" />
```

And replace it with framework reference (see the [Use the ASP.NET Core shared framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) doc):

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

P.S.

Commented out `.AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());` because it makes project uncompilable. Probably you have meant:

```cs
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver())
```

Which requires `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package installed.

Comment: @NguyenTuanAnh was glad to help. If answer works for you - feel free to mark it as accepted one (checkmark on the left)

Comment: I have mark it as a answer. And One thing that I wondering that.
I follow the video here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AopeJjkcRvU
To learn.

And I can't see the difference between my step but the their project  works but mine doesn't work.

Comment: @NguyenTuanAnh no, you have upvoted it. To mark it as an answer you can click on checkmark outline to the left of it. As for the video - I will try to look at it but you need to explain what exactly does not work.